# How to use AWS CLI to update table for a new SortKey?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I have an existing table which only has Partition key (ID) set up. During my development with dynamodb, I found out that I need to update this table to set up the Sort key also. I check the help page from aws dynamodb cli update-table, I don't see a clear way to do this. How can I use cli to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, you **can't add sort key** to the existing table. The list of available options for updating an existing table is [here](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithTables.Basics.html#WorkingWithTables.Basics.UpdateTable) and it includes:

- Modify a table's provisioned throughput settings (for provisioned mode tables).
- Change the table's read/write capacity mode.
- Manipulate global secondary indexes on the table (see Using Global Secondary Indexes in DynamoDB).
- Enable or disable DynamoDB Streams on the table (see Capturing Table Activity with DynamoDB Streams).

Thus, you have **two options** to rectify the issue:

1. Create a new table with the desired sort key and migrate your data.
2. Create a [Global Secondary Indexes](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I had a feeling it's impossible when going through the aws docs, just need a clear "no" from someone. Thanks.

Comment: @ZDunker No problem. Hopefully it will work out either way.

Comment: By the way, I think a **local** secondary index would have been ok as well, because he intends to have it use the same partition key? (not that there is a huge difference between the two, but there are some useful differences around capacity planning and projection which may make it easier to use LSI instead of GSI).

Comment: @NadavHar'El Hi. LSI can be only created when you create your table. Unfortunately, you can't add LSI to an existing table.

Comment: Oops, you're right :-) And the entire premise of the question was that he can't go back in time and change the creation of the table... Oops.